# Как перейти на след строку при считывании из файла

Tags: c++

Я пытаюсь написать функцию считывания из текстового файла со студентами в вектор с студентами. Не могу придумать вариант как можно заполнить например одну область памяти со студентом, заполнить такие поля как фамилия, оценки и т.д. и потом в этом же цикле, переопределить указатель на новую область памяти и записывать в новую область памяти. И по итогу все затолкнуть в вектор. Если 1 я знаю как считать из файла то как сделать несколько? Можно ли пропустить итерацию цикла while по считыванию из файла и перейти на следующую строку в файле? Код ниже:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
using namespace std;
const double GOODMARK = 7.0;//Средний бал выше которого студенты будут считаться отличниками
vector<Student>* students;
Student* student = new Student;
void WorkWithStudent()
{

    char path[256];
    int switcher = 0;
    bool exit = true;
    std::cout << "Please input path for work:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> path;
    students = new vector<Student>[GetCountStudents(path)];
    while (exit)
    {
        std::cout << "Make change:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "0. Exit." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "1. Create new student and write him in file." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2. Search good students from interesting you group." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "3. Print all students" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "4. Fill array students" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "5. Override path" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> switcher;
        switch (switcher)
        {
        case 0:
            exit = false;
            break;
        case 1:
            AddInFile(CreateStudent(), path);
            break;
        case 2:
            SearchGoodStudents(path);
            break;
        case 3:
            GetAllStudents(path);
            break;
        case 4:
            FillArrayStudents(path);
            break;
        case 5:
            std::cout << "Input new path" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> path;
            break;
        default:
            delete students;
            std::cout << "Wrong number!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
Student CreateStudent()//Функция для заполнения студента
{
    std::string Surname;
    int marks[3]{ 0,0,0 };
    int group = 0;
    std::cout << "Input Surname: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> Surname;
    std::cout << "Input number group: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> group;
    std::cout << "Input phys math: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> marks[0];
    std::cout << "Input rate phys: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> marks[1];
    std::cout << "Input rate computer science: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> marks[2];
    Student student(Surname, group, marks[1], marks[0], marks[2]);
    return student;
}
void AddInFile(Student student, char path[])//Функция для записи в файл
{
    try
    {
        std::ofstream file;
        file.open(path, std::ios::app);
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            file << "*" << std::endl;
            file << "Group:" << student.GetGroup() << std::endl;
            file << "Surname:" << student.GetSurname() << std::endl;
            file << "CompScience:" << student.GetCS() << std::endl;
            file << "Math:" << student.GetMath() << std::endl;
            file << "Phys:" << student.GetPhys() << std::endl;
            file << "Average:" << student.GetAverageMark() << std::endl;
            file << "*  " << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error open file!" << std::endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
void GetAllStudents(char path[])    //Получение списка студентов из файла
{
    try
    {
        std::string line;
        std::ifstream file(path);
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            while (std::getline(file, line))
            {

                std::cout << line << std::endl;
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
void SearchGoodStudents(std::string path)// Поиск студентов со средним баллом выше 7
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (*students).size(); i++)
        {
            if ((*students)[i].GetAverageMark() > GOODMARK)
            {
                std::cout << "Good student: " << (*students)[i].GetSurname() << ". With average mark:" << (*students)[i].GetAverageMark() << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
void FillArrayStudents(char path[])//Функция для парсинга из файла данных
{
    Student* student;
    int counter = 0;

    try
    {
        std::string line;
        std::ifstream file(path);
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            while (std::getline(file, line))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < GetCountStudents(path); i++)//цикл для записи заполненных студентов
                {
                    student = new Student;
                    for (bool j = false; j != true;)
                    {
                        if (line.find("*") != std::string::npos)
                        {
                            counter++;

                        }
                        else if (line.find("Group:") != std::string::npos)
                        {
                            (*student).SetGroup(std::stoi(line.substr(_countof("Group:") - 1, line.capacity())));//делаем -1 т.к. не считывает первый символ фамилии

                        }
                        else if (line.find("Surname:") != std::string::npos)
                        {
                            (*student).SetSurname(line.substr(_countof("Surname:") - 1, line.capacity()));//делаем -1 т.к. не считывает первый символ фамилии

                        }
                        else if (line.find("CompScience:") != std::string::npos)
                        {
                            (*student).SetCS(std::stoi(line.substr(_countof("CompScience:") - 1, line.capacity())));//делаем -1 т.к. не считывает первый символ фамилии

                        }
                        else if (line.find("Math:") != std::string::npos)
                        {
                            (*student).SetMath(std::stoi(line.substr(_countof("Math:") - 1, line.capacity())));//делаем -1 т.к. не считывает первый символ фамилии

                        }
                        else if (line.find("Phys:") != std::string::npos)
                        {
                            (*student).SetPhys(std::stoi(line.substr(_countof("Phys:") - 1, line.capacity())));//делаем -1 т.к. не считывает первый символ фамилии

                        }
                        else if (line.find("Average:") != std::string::npos)
                        {
                            (*student).SetAverageMark(std::stod(line.substr(_countof("Average:") - 1, line.capacity())));//делаем -1 т.к. не считывает первый символ фамилии

                        }
                        else if (counter / 2 == 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    (*students).push_back((*student));
                }

            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
int GetCountStudents(char path[])
{
    int count = 0;
    try
    {
        std::string line;
        std::ifstream file(path);
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            while (std::getline(file, line))
            {
                if (line.find("Surname:") != std::string::npos)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Здесь нужна помощь в функции `FillArrayStudents()`. Совсем ничего в голову не лезет. И через 2 `for` пытался сделать и подумываю через 2 `while` но это ужас будет при том не факт что заработает. У кого есть какие идеи по этому поводу?
Записывает в файл в таком виде:

```
    *
   Group:666
   Surname:Yenk
   CompScience:7
   Math:7
   Phys:8
   Average:7.33333
   *    
   *
   Group:123
   Surname:Ivanov
   CompScience:7
   Math:5
   Phys:6
   Average:6
   *    
   *
   Group:45
   Surname:Petrov
   CompScience:8
   Math:8
   Phys:8
   Average:8
   *
```

Comment: А можно пример файла? Хотя бы пару строк, чтобы понимать как организовано хранение данных...

Comment: @Iceman добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно конечно читать построчно, но предложу Вам другой вариант - считать всё в буфер и распарсить. Желательно для этого создать некий объект, управляющий списком студентов. В общем, вот пример:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

struct Student{
    std::string Group, Surname;
    std::map<std::string, int> subjects;
    float Average(){ // Зачем хранить Average как отдельную переменную?
        float accum = 0;
        for(auto si = subjects.begin(); si != subjects.end(); ++si) accum += si->second;
        return accum / subjects.size();
    }
};

class StudentsManager{
    std::vector<Student> students;
    std::vector<std::string> subjects;

    std::string GetValue(const std::string &source, const std::string &lb, std::string marker){
        int begin = source.find(marker);
        if (-1 == begin) return "";
        begin+= marker.size();
        int end = source.find(lb, begin);
        if (-1 == end) end = source.size();
        return source.substr(begin, end - begin);
    }

    bool ParseData(const std::string &buffer){ // Передаём ссылку, нам лишняя копия файла не нужна в памяти
        std::string obj_delim("*"); // разделитель объектов
        std::string linebreak("\n");
        // определяем как устроен разрыв сток - по \r\n или \n
        // (можно стереть следующие 2 строки, если это заведомо известно)
        if (-1 != buffer.find("\r\n")) linebreak = "\r\n";
        else if(-1 == buffer.find(linebreak)) return false;

        int begin = -1;

        while(++begin < buffer.size()){
            begin = buffer.find(obj_delim, begin);
            if (-1 == begin) break;
            int end = buffer.find(obj_delim, ++begin);
            if (-1 == end) break;

            std::string obj_buf = buffer.substr(begin,end);

            Student student;
            student.Group = GetValue(obj_buf, linebreak, "Group:");
            student.Surname = GetValue(obj_buf, linebreak, "Surname:");
            if (!student.Group.empty() && !student.Surname.empty()){
                for(auto si = subjects.begin(); si != subjects.end(); ++si){
                    auto mark = GetValue(obj_buf, linebreak, *si);
                    if (mark.empty()) continue;
                    if (auto val = std::stoi(mark)) student.subjects[*si] = val;
                }
                students.push_back(student);
            }
            begin = end;
        }
        return !students.empty();
    }
public:
    bool AddSubject(std::string subject){
        subject+= ":";
        auto si = subjects.begin();
        for(;si!= subjects.end(); ++si) if (subject == *si) break;
        if (si != subjects.end()) return false; // есть уже такой
        subjects.emplace_back(subject);
        return true;
    }

    bool LoadData(const char *filenane){
        // Открываем и читаем весь файл в буфер...
        // Если не нравится классический метод fopen / fread / fclose, можно переписать на std::ifstream
        auto file = fopen(filenane, "rb");
        if (!file) return false;
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        std::string buffer(ftell(file),0); // выделяем буфер под файл
        rewind(file);
        if (buffer.size() != fread(&buffer[0], 1, buffer.size(), file)){
            fclose(file);
            return false;
        }
        fclose(file);
        return ParseData(buffer);
    }

    void ShowStudents(){
        for(auto si = students.begin(); si != students.end(); ++si){
            auto student = &(*si); // работаем с указателем на студента, чтобы не копировать лишний раз
            printf("*\nGroup: %s\nSurname: %s", student->Group.c_str(), student->Surname.c_str());
            if (!student->subjects.empty()){
                for(auto ssi = student->subjects.begin(); ssi != student->subjects.end(); ++ssi)
                    printf("\n%s %d", ssi->first.c_str(), ssi->second);
                printf("\nAverage: %f", student->Average());
            }
            printf("\n*\n");
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) return 1;
    StudentsManager smgr;
    smgr.AddSubject("CompScience");
    smgr.AddSubject("Math");
    smgr.AddSubject("Phys");
    // Список дисциплин тоже можно читать из файла
    smgr.LoadData(argv[1]);
    smgr.ShowStudents();
    return 0;
}
```

Остальной функционал по вводу из консоли, добавлению, удалению и т.д. уже можно по аналогии сделать

Comment: Я постоянно знал что у меня есть какая то мелочь которую надо сделать чтобы у меня все заработало и я ее нашел. Спасибо за ваш вариант решения моей проблемы

Answer (score 0):

По итогу решил проблему через переписывание функции с проходом:

```
    void FillArrayStudents(char path[])//Функция для парсинга из файла данных
{
    auto temp = new Student[GetCountStudents(path)];
    try
    {
        std::string line;
        std::ifstream file(path);
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GetCountStudents(path); i++)
            {
                while (std::getline(file, line))
                    if (line.find("*") != std::string::npos)
                    {
                        students->push_back(temp[i]);
                        i++;

                    }
                    else if (line.find("Group:") != std::string::npos)
                    {
                        temp[i].SetGroup(std::stoi(line.substr(_countof("Group:") - 1, line.capacity())));//делаем -1 т.к. не считывает первый символ фамилии

                    }
                    else if (line.find("Surname:") != std::string::npos)
                    {
                        temp[i].SetSurname(line.substr(_countof("Surname:") - 1, line.capacity()));//делаем -1 т.к. не считывает первый символ фамилии

                    }
                    else if (line.find("CompScience:") != std::string::npos)
                    {
                        temp[i].SetCS(std::stoi(line.substr(_countof("CompScience:") - 1, line.capacity())));//делаем -1 т.к. не считывает первый символ фамилии

                    }
                    else if (line.find("Math:") != std::string::npos)
                    {
                        temp[i].SetMath(std::stoi(line.substr(_countof("Math:") - 1, line.capacity())));//делаем -1 т.к. не считывает первый символ фамилии

                    }
                    else if (line.find("Phys:") != std::string::npos)
                    {
                        temp[i].SetPhys(std::stoi(line.substr(_countof("Phys:") - 1, line.capacity())));//делаем -1 т.к. не считывает первый символ фамилии

                    }
                    else if (line.find("Average:") != std::string::npos)
                    {
                        temp[i].SetAverageMark(std::stod(line.substr(_countof("Average:") - 1, line.capacity())));//делаем -1 т.к. не считывает первый символ фамилии

                    }
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```